# Steering wheel wobbles at low speed roll, car shakes at specific speeds, possibly worsening

Tags: steering-wheel

When my car rolls forward, the steering wheel turns quickly right then left, right then left, back and forth, the same small amount each time.  At higher speeds the car shakes, and it seems to shake the worst when just at 60-65 mph.  The problems seems a lot worse after a drive to PA and back from Washington DC.

The tread on my tires is definitely low, Im saving to get new ones.  The alignment isn't centered either, it pulls slightly to the right when I let go of the wheel, but I never saw it as a problem.

Could this be from the lower control arm bushing? A mechanic told me that it would need to be changed soon.  I looked at them though and they seemed to still be intact.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: You have a bad front tire, get it replaced soon.

Comment: Check the lugs nuts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some broken belts in your tire. Do any of the tires have bulges in the side walls? I'd have an honest mechanic check the spindle, hub, check that all steering components are properly seated, just have your whole steering rack checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Could be any of the things mentioned-buckled wheel or tyre is most obvious and cheapest to change

Answer (score 0):

Check out tie rod ends, and other suspension parts for play. also possible it could be a warped rotor causing this, check steering stuff first though.

Comment: Also i forgot to type, that if your mechanic mentioned that, you should probably get it checked out or even see for yourself if there is play. Basically sounds like suspension.

Comment: Hi SPITFINGERS and welcome.  FYI, you should be able to edit your post - look for the "edit" link under it.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for that. will remember for next time!